# Windows 7 RC?

Tags: windows-7, operating-system

Does anybody know when the RC for Windows 7 will be coming out, or where to get it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this article](http://www.guardian.co.uk/technology/blog/2009/may/01/windows7-rc-free), May 5. That's for the general public. According to the [Windows 7 Team Blog](http://windowsteamblog.com/blogs/windows7/archive/2009/04/24/windows-7-release-candidate-update.aspx):

> I’m pleased to share that the RC is on
>   track for April 30th for  download by
>   MSDN and TechNet subscribers. Broader,
>   public availability will begin on May
>   5th.

Here is it on [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/downloads/default.aspx?pv=36:350) and [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/subscriptions/downloads/default.aspx?PV=36:350:DVD:en:x86).

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, it's meant to be available to the public on May 5th, and it's on MSDN and Technet now.

However, why not wait until, say, this time next week (May 9th)? If you imagine it's not actually out for a few more days, you're likely to have a much less frustrating experience downloading it.

Comment: Good advice on waiting to download, last time I tried to download ubuntu the day it came out it took me almost an hour and thirty minutes.

Comment: 90 minutes - wow, that must have seemed like an _age_ ...

Comment: @Alnitak: It did, I'll never make that mistake again.

Comment: Downloads from MSDN are downloading ok now, taking about an hour on 20Mb cable

Comment: @Alnitak,
It took 24 hours for my machine to download Windows 7 beta 7000!

Answer (score 1):

MSDN and Technet already have it.

Answer (score 0):

It will be publicly available May 5th.

Answer (score 0):

It's available to the public from May 5th, and already available since April 30th to MSDN and Technet subscribers, and since about April 21st it has apparently been available from the Pirate Bay...

If you already have an activation key from the Beta release, it will also work on the Release Candidate.